# Why the type did not deduced to `const` type in both auto and template function cases?

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

This is my first question here and I hope I have added all relevant information to have a minimal verifiable complete program. In case you need more information kindly comment to me.

I am learning C++ template programming and type deduction.

- **case I**: I used `auto` keyword for the type and cast the integer to a `const double`.
- **case II**: I used a template function(`type_fun`) and  told the compiler to do the deduction to `const double` by casting as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
void type_fun(T t)
{
    std::cout << "From type function: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same_v<const double, decltype(t)> << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same_v<double, decltype(t)> << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    auto t = static_cast<const double>(1);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same_v<const double, decltype(t)> << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same_v<double, decltype(t)> << std::endl;

    type_fun(static_cast<const double>(1));
}
```

However, the results are the same. The program says the deduced type is a `non-const double`. Why the compiler neglected the `const`?

What do I need to do, to achieve the deduced type to be same as the `static_cast`ed type?

Comment: The dupe doesn't explicitly say what you have to do for your second question, that said, you just add `const`.  `auto t` -> `const auto t` and `(T t)` -> `(const T t)`

Comment: @NathanOliver That means, along with `static_cast<const double>`, I need to do as you mentioned, right?

Comment: Rather than `(const T t)`, which is _always_ const, prefer `(T&& t)`, which matches the caller perfectly.

Comment: @Using Kind of.  You really don't need `static_cast<const double>(1)` for the auto case.  `const auto = 1;` would give you what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may sound strange, but `const` is only for variables (and other things), but not for constants, since constants are already always `const`.

In your code:

```
auto t = static_cast<const double>(1);
```

`t` will get the type `double` and this explains the behavior you see.

> What do I need to do, to achieve the deduced type to be same as the static_casted type?

You cannot differentiate a `const double` and `double` when this is passed as actual parameter to a function. Both are passed by value and both are 100% const (also without `const`) from the callers point of view. The function cannot modify the value of the caller. So the compiler makes no effort to differentiate between them.

If you want the `const double` variant to be printed in the template function you have to make it:

```
template<typename T>
void type_fun(const T t)
{
    std::cout << "From type function: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same_v<const double, decltype(t)> << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same_v<double, decltype(t)> << std::endl;
}
```

But this variant will then *always* print the `const double` variant, regardless of the type which was passed in. The const near a formal parameter means in this case that the value which was passed by value (non-const or const) cannot be changed *within* the function.

`const` is used in too many contexts for too many purposes. It can be confusing.